# Flask WTForms Validator Message changes layout

Tags: html, flask, wtforms

I'm using WTForms in Flask and am validating Form inputs on submission.
The problem I'm facing occurs with the use of wtforms `validators`. in particular, the error messages on validation are changing the layout of my HTML page. Code is as follows, Screenshots of changes are also included.

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FieldList, FormField, HiddenField, validators
from wtforms.fields import StringField


class SingleGuessForm(FlaskForm):
    # load list of accepted vocab
    class Meta:
        csrf = False
    with open('accepted_words.txt') as f:
        l = f.readlines()
    l = [s.rstrip() for s in l]

    guess = StringField(validators=[validators.Required(message='Guess is required'), validators.AnyOf(l, message='Guess is not in vocabulary.')])


class SentenceForm(FlaskForm):
    # Disable CSRF for this class.
    class Meta:
        csrf = False

    guess_form = FieldList(FormField(SingleGuessForm), min_entries=5, max_entries=5) 

    id = HiddenField()
```

**page.html** (relevant part)

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="overall_guess_form">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="audio_elements">
                    <audio controls class="sentence_audio"
                           id="{{ form.id.data }}">
                        <source src="{{ form.path.data }}"
                                type="audio/wav">
                    </audio>
                    <span class="iconify check_mark"
                          data-icon="emojione:check-mark-button"
                          style="visibility: hidden;"
                          data-inline="false"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100%">
            <form class="guess_fields">
                {% for single_word_guess in form.guess_form %}
                    {{ single_word_guess.form.guess(class_='guess_box') }}
                    {{ single_word_guess.form.hidden_tag() }}
                    {{ single_word_guess.form.crsf_token }}
                    {# print errors if someone made one. Let's see if this works #}
                     {% for field, errors in single_word_guess.form.errors.items() %}
                        <small class="form-text text-muted ">
                            {{ ', '.join(errors) }}
                        </small>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.crsf_token }}

    <div class="input submit" style="text-align: center">
        <input id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
               name="submitButton"
               value="Continue"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**style.css**

```
.guess_fields {
    display: inline;
    margin: auto;
}

.guess_box {
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 18%;
}
```

This is what my rendered HTML looks like before submission - the input text fields are nicely put next to each other, as they are supposed to:
[image]

But after sumission, the layout changes to this:

[image]

I've tried making the error message shorter (just 'test') because I suspected the text below to be too long, but that didn't make a difference. How do I keep my input fields in row here, with the potential error messages appearing below its corresponding TextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the source code in your browser before and after submitting the form ? I suspect that the issue is caused by the legends (`<small class="form-text text-muted ">`), that appear after submission, when errors are reported.

I guess you are using Bootstrap, so I suggest that you have a look at the [form layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#server-side) help, to restructure your form as an inline form. The available Bootstrap classes should suffice.